# CRM 2011 RollUp 12 refresh grid

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Since the rollup 12 update we can't use this javascript code anymore to refresh grid

from ribbon button onClick (ribbon on grid page)

```
window.document.all.crmGrid.Refresh();
```

or from ribbon button onClick (ribbon on homepage) to refresh parent grid

```
window.top.opener.document.getElementById('crmGrid').Refresh();
```

How we should refresh grid now?

Answer (score 7):

It no longer works because the method you were using was unsupported. I assume that you are referring to updating a subgrid on a form. The correct way to refresh a grid is to use the `refresh` method of the grid control as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_refresh)

Comment: +1 for unsupported (hitting the DOM directly). I think RU12 is going to catch out so many people on bits like this.

Comment: Not the sub-grid. I added a button to ribbon (Mscrm.HomepageGrid). When I click this button some business logic runs and update selected records from grid. When this action done I want to refresh this grid. Previously I used window.document.all.crmGrid.Refresh(); for this purpose.

Comment: And the second. When I open a form from grid and run custom action on form I also want to update form and parent grid. Used window.top.opener.document.getElementById('crmGrid').Refresh(); before. The same things happen when you click Save on form. Current form and parent grid will be refreshed. I need the same functionality for my own button.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you need to refresh form and Maingrid(from where record was opened).

//Refreshing form

window.location.reload(true);

//Refreshing Maingrid

window.parent.opener.document.getElementById("crmGrid").control.refresh();

I have tried in CRM Online(update Roll 12).